Comfy UI - GPU not being utilised on queues (GTX 1080)
I'm trying to use ComfyUI with my GTX 1080
What I'm confused about is that I'm using run_nvidia_gpu and in the logs it's recognising my GTX (see below)
Total VRAM 8192 MB, total RAM 8109 MB
Set vram state to: NORMAL_VRAM
Device: cuda:0 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 : cudaMallocAsync

But when I queue the prompt, I see almost no usage at all for my GPU and my PC ends up freezing half of the time
Instead I see usage from my D: drive (even though it's in C: ?) & the memory usage caps out although that's to be expected
I can't find answers on this anywhere, help would be appreciated!
If there's any logs people need to clarify anything, let me know!
https://i.sstatic.net/26gEf9ZM.png
